# Haskell installation

Tags: haskell, installation

I am trying to install Haskell, and the installation was successfull, but it tells me that I have to adjust my PATH variable? Here are the instructions to finalize the installations and be able to run Haskell:

```
In order to run ghc and cabal, you need to adjust your PATH 
variable.
You may want to source '/Users/hannahmcdermott/.ghcup/env' in 
your shell configuration to do so (e.g. ~/.bashrc).
```

Could someone tell me what to type into the terminal?:) Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

What the instructions are literally telling you is to add the line

```sh
source /Users/hannahmcdermott/.ghcup/env
```

(or shorter, `. ~/.ghcup/env`) to the file `~/.bashrc`. You can do that with one interactive command:

```sh
echo '. ~/.ghcup/env' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then, whenever you open a new bash terminal window (which always loads the `~/.bashrc` file), the necessary environment variable should be loaded. At least this works in a Linux system; not sure if it needs adaption on MacOS.

What that `env` script you're invoking there does is in turn simply adding some stuff to bash's `$PATH` environment variable, which means you get to call programs in the `~/.cabal/bin` directory without needing to specify their exact path.

Comment: I am getting 'Permission denied' and I am not sure why?

Comment: When running `echo XYZ >> ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Given that `PATH` is inherited, something that modifies it should probably just go in `.bash_profile` so that it only gets added once, when you first log in. (This goes doubly for macOS, since by default most terminal emulators start a login shell instead of an ordinary interactive shell.)

Comment: @chepner makes sense, why not explain in a separate answer.

Comment: I think the issue of *which* file to update is borderline off-topic here, and trying to cater everyone's possible shell blows up too quickly. (Very shortly, it's no longer going to be a valid assumption that a macOS user's shell *is* `bash`, as macOS 10.15 makes `zsh` the default user shell.) Also, I don't know what's actually in the file, so I don't know if there's a *reason* for it to appear in the interactive shell configuration file rather than the login file.